# UITextChecker Custom Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am curious if anyone knows of a way to use the the iPhone/iPad built-in spellchecker but use a custom dictionary? Basically UITextChecker loaded with an array of words that I provide to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot provide a custom dictionary in the current version of the SDK.

If you need this functionality immediately, you could implement it yourself using [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) to display the suggestions (which is how the framework does it). That isn't a small task though.